# player falling into the terrain when falling on it

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, terrain, collider

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uc2sys7ZFd686UkQlYAMEDZekFEHZcAr/view?usp=sharing

as u see in the video when I try to jump from the mountain the player just goes through the terrain as if it's not there but I can still move normal and I noticed that whenever I move fast while being off the ground the problem appears like when I first started this level I was jumping and returning to the ground very slowly and whenever I jump and move fast towards a hell the problem occurs so I increased the gravity so that I can't move while jumping but still if I move fast while in the air the player won't collide with the terrain but when I move normally or fast on the ground non of that happen's can anyone help me?

I searched on the internet and I found nothing related to this.

---

terrain 1 properties:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VwelecESLjfD7UseP6lmQ0Kkg-3pwg67/view?usp=sharing

terrain 2 properties:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZH-cIBXlhBMPbmkgZXkQmjt-QVpe6MLu/view?usp=sharing

player properties:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vTp3TSuIDcYm3orWhy5X3kw6wwBmwNcE/view?usp=sharing

---

here are the codes used for this:

mouse lock:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mouselock : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }
}
```

player movement:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class playermove2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("movement")] 
    private float movespeed = 10f;

    [SerializeField] float airmultiplier = 0.4f;
    [SerializeField] Transform oriantation;

    private float horizontalmovement;

    private float verticalmovement;

    private float rbdrag = 6f;

    private Vector3 movedirection;

    public float movementmultiplier = 10f;

    public bool isgrounded;

    private float playerhight = 1.8f;

    public float jumpforce = 8;

    public Rigidbody rb;
    
    public float grounddrag = 6f;

    public float aridrag = 2f;

    public int number;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (number == 11)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("finish scene2");
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            movespeed = 25;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            movespeed = 20;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isgrounded)
        {
            jump();
        }
        print(isgrounded);
        myinput();
        controledrag();
    }

    private void myinput()
    {
        horizontalmovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        verticalmovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        movedirection = oriantation.forward * verticalmovement + oriantation.right * horizontalmovement;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveplayer();
    }

    void moveplayer()
    {
        if (isgrounded)
        {
            rb.AddForce(movedirection.normalized * movespeed * movementmultiplier, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.AddForce(movedirection.normalized * movespeed * movementmultiplier * airmultiplier, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
    }

    void controledrag()
    {
        if (isgrounded)
        {
            rb.drag = grounddrag;

        }
        else
        {
            rb.drag = aridrag;
        }
    }

    void jump()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpforce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

collisions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class collisions2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public playermove2 player;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.layer == 6)
        {
            player.isgrounded = true;

        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.layer == 6)
        {
            player.isgrounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

camera movement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform cameraposition;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = cameraposition.position;
    }
}
```

player look:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerlook : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField] private float sensX;
   [SerializeField] private float sensY;

   [SerializeField] Transform cam;
   [SerializeField] Transform oriantation;

   private float mouseX;
   private float mouseY;

   private float multiplier = 0.01f;

   private float xRotation;
   private float yRotation;

   private void Start()
   {
      Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
      Cursor.visible = false;

   }

   private void Update()
   {
      mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
      mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");

      yRotation += mouseX * sensX * multiplier;
      xRotation -= mouseY * sensY * multiplier;

      xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
      cam.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
      oriantation.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler( 0, yRotation, 0);
   }
}



triggers:

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class triggers2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public playermove2 playerMove;
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.layer == 8)
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            playerMove.number++;
        }
    }
}
```

score and high score:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class scoreandhighscore2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text highscoretext;
    public Text scoretext;
    public playermove2 playermove;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        highscoretext.text = "high score: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        scoretext.text = "score: " + playermove.number.ToString();

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if ( playermove.number > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", playermove.number);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Could you share the player and terrain properties? Make sure you have a collider attached to both and not a trigger

Comment: I shared the properties of the terrains and the player I have a terrain collider on both of the terrains and a capsule collider on the player and as u can see I can walk normally but when I go fast in the air the problem occurs it is just in the air, so when I fall I fall fast because my gravity is set to 55 so the problem occurs, and if I lower the gravity I will move fast when I jump so the problem will occur when I jump and walk.

Answer (score 0):

sooooo I solved the problem the solution is just converting the collision detection to continuous and just like that the player won't break through the terrain I hope this is helpful for other people

here's a pic of what I did:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ati8xQFQxwqAg8eJnmZzrs8D05HGuJLs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).